# Using C#, how to programmatically determine if a certificate in a Windows certificate store has been disabled

Tags: c#, windows, certificate, pki, x509certificate2

I'm currently working on refining communications between mutually authenticated client/server applications using HTTPS.  I am currently building validation logic into a C# client to help identify configuration issues when a TLS connection fails.  In verifying the connection, I validate that the root CA certificate presented by the server is installed on the client, in the appropriate store, and is valid.  I'm using `X509Store` to pull the `X509Certificate2`, and validating it using `X509Chain`.

My issue is that the certificate will report as valid even if the certificate has been disabled via MMC.  So the TLS connection will fail, despite the chain reporting as valid.

[image: Certificate Properties]

It's an unlikely case, but one I'd like to handle by reporting something like "Could not connect because root CA is disabled."

Could anyone point me in the direction of a .NET or Win32 call that could be made to determine the value of "Certificate Purposes" for a certificate?  Or to read the "Certificate Status" for a cert?

[image: Certificate Status]

I read through MSDN's listing of what's in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace, and started looking into CryptoAPI and CNG, but didn't find anything so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dialog does not "disable" a certificate it disables it "for all purposes". What this means is it counts as having an empty Enhanced Key Usage extension for purposes of EKU validation.

Normally a root certificate (or an intermediate CA certificate) will not have an EKU extension, so if you do a chain build with any ApplicationPolicy value it will be a match.  Once you set it to Disable for all purposes you'll get a chain error `X509ChainStatusFlags.NotValidForUsage`.

If you want to build something for validating TLS you'd check either the Server Authentication or Client Authentication EKUs (depending on what you're checking):

```
// Server EKU or Client EKU
Oid eku = forServer ? new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") : new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2");

// Test if it's valid for that purpose
chain.ChainPolicy.ApplicationPolicy.Add(eku);
```

If you want to "Disable" a root CA altogether, add a copy of the certificate to the Disallowed store (called "Untrusted Certificates" in the UI).  That will result in a chain build producing `X509ChainStatusFlags.ExplicitDistrust`.

Comment: Outstanding!  Thank you for the detailed explanation.  As I'm checking for a root CA, rather than the SSL cert itself, it doesn't have an EKU extension (exactly as you said).  However, adding the oid for "Key Usage" (2.5.29.15) to the `ApplicationPolicy` works like a charm.

Comment: I would say it is unrealiable solution. In a fact, not all browsers require the full chain be valid for specified usage and check only if leaf certificate has desired usage only. If you want to get root CA cert usages via properties -- check it. Because there might be a case when usages are prohibited on intermediate CA level. As the result, root CA is ok, but the code will fail, while connection works normally.

Comment: @crypt32 EKU must be a proper subset. If the intermediate blocks an EKU the leaf can't have it.  The Key Usage that he said he's using for his check is irrelevant, since it's asking for that OID from the EKU set it will never hit, but will be allowed when no EKU is present.

Comment: `EKU must be a proper subset` -- technically yes, but in reality it isn't. Like I said, there are number of scenarios when applications only check if leaf certificate contains desired EKU and don't care about the rest of the chain.

Comment: Check this one issued by Comodo: https://www.sysadmins.lv/content/random/ssl-weak-eku.crt -- this is an example when EKU is not required to be a proper subset. And the certificate would be valid if not SHA1.

Comment: I am post-validating client/server certificates after TLS failure using .NET `HttpWebRequest`, which gives terrible info, to give better troubleshooting information.  `HttpWebRequest` already validated the client chain locally, and matched to server presented issuers, prior to validating server cert locally (last step, oddly).  All I had left to check was "cert exists/is trusted, but has usage(s) disabled."  For the CA root, without EKU, I checked for Key Usage, which appears to reflect disabled usages.  I didn't know how to check for specific value flags on that oid; reading more today. :-)